# How to naturally connect objects of different shapes

Tags: edges, faces

I want to connect objects of different shapes naturally. The part I'm going to connect to is the edge that has an empty face.

Edge bridge does not apply because it has different shapes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Grid Fill would fit your needs, however, it requires to have somewhat even number of edges on each side so you'll need to subdivide the simpler side https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#grid-fill

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way using Grid Fill.

UPDATE: check out the "Bridge Edge Loop" option proposed by @RayMairlot in the comments. It may be best suited to your need.

ref: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#grid-fill

1. Subdivide the side to match the number of vertices on the other side
2. Create supporting Edges
3. Select edges on both sides
4. Grid fill
5. repeat for the other sides.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: After subdividing you can just select the loop of vertices on the cube and the loop on the cylinder and choose 'Bridge Edge Loops' from the *Edge* menu. Increase the number of cuts for a a smoother result.

Comment: Thanks @RayMairlot  I must say I don't like the end result so much with a weird bumpy profile that sticks out so using Bridge Edge loop might be a better option, specially when a Subdiv Modifier  is used on the object.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. I have one question for you. After connecting the edges of the two objects, the cube cannot apply the loop cut to faces of the entire cube. More specifically, only one side, not the whole side, applies the loop cut. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: I noticed that too... this is due to the imbalance in vertices creating weird topology on the cube. I think the only way to fix it is to subdivide the entire cube instead of just the connecting edgeloop.